# Ordenamiento Topologico C#

Tags: c#, ordenamiento

esto es un problema que tengo que no tengo ni la mínima idea de que esta pasando

Quiero ordenar de forma topologica una matriz pero por alguna razon no me imprime lo que debe de imprimir

```
public int EncontradoIO()
        {
            bool encontrado = false;
            int n = 0;
            for(n = 0; n < nodos; n++)
            {
                if (grado[n] == 0)
                {
                    encontrado = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (encontrado)
                return n;
            else
                return -1;
        }

        public void DecrementaGrado(int pNodo)
        {
            grado[pNodo] = -1;
            int n = 0;
            for(n = 0; n < nodos; n++)
            {
                if(mAdyacencia[pNodo,n] == 1)
                {
                    grado[n]--;
                }
            }
        }
```

con este código que esta en una clase debe de ordenarlo y después con este código debe de imprimir

```
do
            {
                nodo = mg.EncontradoIO();
                if (nodo != -1)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} --> ", nodo);
                    mg.DecrementaGrado(nodo);
                }
            } while (nodo != -1);
```

el error es que no imprime correctamente la matriz de adyacencia, se supone que deberia de imprimir 0--> 1--> 4-->3-->-->6-->2-->5 o deberia de ser de otro orden creo pero solo me imprime 5-->6

Comment: y cual es el error/problema???

Comment: el error es que no imprime correctamente la matriz de adyacencia, se supone que deberia de imprimir 0--> 1--> 4-->3-->-->6-->2-->5 o deberia de ser de otro orden creo pero solo me imprime 5-->6

Comment: agrégalo a tu post

Comment: sabes como arreglar el problema que tengo?

Comment: no pero si se evaluar lo que le hace falta a una pregunta ...y entre mas datos coloques que sean necesarios mejor visibilidad tendrá tu pregunta y mas fácil será de responder.

Comment: ¿Qué datos le pasas para que tenga que imprimir ese resultado que esperas? Y sobre todo, ¿dónde se los pasas? No veo el punto de entrada al código que pegas, no sabría reproducir el error.